# How to save content changes made by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a table with some rows and cells.
I can edit inner table content using jquery.
But how i can save this edits ?
my table:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <th>Teams</th>
    <th>Points</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Arsenal</td>
    <td id="points">35</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Liverpool</td>
    <td>33</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Chelsea</td>
    <td>33</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Man City</td>
    <td>32</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Everton</td>
    <td>31</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

my Jquery code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var val = $("#points").text();
    $("#ss").click(function () {
        val++;
        $("#points").text(val);
    })
})
</script>

<button id="ss">Inc</button>
```

By clicking on `button` with "ss" `id` , the value of `td` with "points" `id` increases.
So how i can save and update this increase to currently file (without refresh page)?

Comment: use javascript cookie

Comment: I want save changes permanent.

Comment: Save where? Which file? Use ajax if you have to increase and save on the Web server. Use local storage if you need to store on the client, and don't need to access this value on the server.

Comment: @AliN11 if  permanent why not use Database or something else on serverside

Comment: Save this changes to current file.current table.

Comment: @rajeshkakawat : no different.then how i can save this changes without refresh page ?

Comment: @AliN11 use ajax to save it

Comment: My main question is that how to update content inside a file using web browser ? not changing the source of that file.

Comment: yeah.I want that ajax code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Html5 Storage jQuery Plugin

If you are using jQuery in your projects and you want to use Local Storage or Session Storage, this is your library. If user's browser doesn't support them it will use cookies instead.

REFERENCE

https://github.com/artberri/jquery-html5storage/

**USING AJAX**

```
$(function(){
    var val = $("#points").text();
    $("#ss").click(function () {
        val++;
        $("#points").text(val);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "some.php",
            data: { points: val }
            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        });
    })
})
```

some.php

```
$point = $_POST['points'];
//CODE TO SAVE TO DATABASE GOES HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

To store :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var val = $("#points").text();
$("#ss").click(function () {
    val++;
   window.localStorage.setItem("storedValue", val);
    $("#points").text(val);
})
 })
</script>
```

To get value :

```
var value = window.localStorage.getItem("storedValue");
```

Comment: you can clear specific  value like this : window.localStorage.removeItem("storedValue"); , all values using - window.localStorage.clear(); , am not sure about is it permanent or not . May be all data cleared when u clear the browser cache.